# Gnome Contacts in Ubuntu 23.04 of all lists in Evolution are shown - how to avoid some lists?

Tags: gnome, backup, ubuntu-gnome, gnome-contacts

I have 2 contact lists, which I synchronize with my local Nextcloud server through carddav. As this may have problems, I made special folders with lists, where I copy the carddav lists for having the old lists as backup. In gnome contacts these for backup reasons created contact lists are shown in gnome contacts, too. Exactly this I want to avoid, but I do not know how. Is there any way to avoid showing me the backup lists, too? In settings I can not choose which lists are shown.